# So I have to rotate an array by one position but withou allocating extra space other than the array. Is this a correct solution?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, rotation

Here is my solution. Is it correct? Ignore bits/stdc++.h etc. I just want to know if it only uses the space allocated for the vector.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Size of array?\n";
    cin >> n;
    int x[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Input x[" << i << "]:\n";
        cin >> x[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << x[i] << "; ";
    }
    for (int i = 1; i<n; i++) {
        swap(x[0],x[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << x[i] << "; ";
    }
}
```

Comment: If this works and compiles use codereview instead of stackoverflow please.

Comment: To begin with your "array" is actually not valid because C++ doesn't really have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: you cannot use dynamic array in stack. so above code is wrong. if you wnat dynamic array you should malloc or use new or use **std::vector**

Comment: Also never use [`<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h), not even for simple examples. Both the VLA and the header are truly bad habits commonly exposed through so-called "competition" sites. And such sites are not meant for learning anything, unless all you want to learn are really bad habits(habits so bad they can actually make you unemployable).

Comment: *Ignore bits/stdc++.h etc.* -- Why couldn't you have simply put `#include <algorithm>` and then `#include <iostream>`?  Then there wouldn't have been a need to mention anything about that header.

Comment: Your swap loop only accesses valid values in the `x` array. It's valid.

Comment: Maybe OT, but `<algorithm>` already has a function for rotating a range of elements: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate

Comment: @N0ll_Boy i didnt want a variable size array i want an array that only takes as much space as it needs

Comment: @Some programmer dude i need to have an array of a size that the user inputs, that size will never change after that, should i use an input file then?

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 cant use built in algorithms

Comment: @VoicuVlad `int n; ... int x[n];` isn't C++. GCC copied it from C, where it is called a "variable length array"

Comment: `int x[n];` *is* a variable lenght array. Thats how they are called. See here: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). If you want an array with size determined only at runtime but fixed after construction, the simple way is to use a `std::vector` and not add or remove elements after construction

Comment: on the one hand you ask "Is this a correct solution?" but on the other hand the requirements are not clearly stated in the question. The "correct" way would not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and would use `std::rotate`. Did you test the code for same example cases? What more do you want to know?

Comment: @voicu-vlad then you should use standard library containers such as std::array, std::vector,etc they are handling size for you(but beware you said you want as much space as it needs so dont forget use reserve method on vector).

Comment: thanks everyone, std::vector always seemed overkill for some simple problems but i'll start using it more frequently

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 if i would use x[10] and then use n to store a logical value would it be c++

Comment: imho using a compiler extension for something that is readily available in standard portable C++ is overkill. I don't understand your last comment. Arrays sizes must be compile time constants. You can do `const int x = 10; int x[10];`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 i wanted to mean if it is ok to declare my array of 10 elements and only use 6 elements and declare a variable (n) to store the number of used elements (6) to use in the algorithms i create ( for example the algorithm from the question wouldnt work with a array that is not fully used unless i tell it how many elements does the array actuslly store ( from a logic point of view, 10 would be the actual size and 6 the logical size)

Comment: sure, you can do that. You are just wasting some memory and you need to handle the case of user entering something bigger than `10` for `n` to not access the array out of bounds. If you use a `std::vector` properly, both can be avoided completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters variable length arrays like this

```
int n;
cout << "Size of array?\n";
cin >> n;
int x[n];
```

is not a standard C++ feature. Instead you should use the standard container `std::vector<int>`.

To rotate an array or an object of the type `std::vector<int>` you can use the standard algorithm `std::rotate`.

As for your code then if you want to rotate the array left then this loop

```
for (int i = 1; i<n; i++) {
        swap(x[0],x[i]);
}
```

should be written like

```
for (int i = 1; i<n; i++) {
        swap(x[i-1],x[i]);
}
```

Otherwise your loop rotates an array right.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    for ( const auto &item : v )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    for ( size_t i = 1; i < v.size(); i++ )
    {
        std::swap( v[i-1], v[i] );
    }
    
    for ( const auto &item : v )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 
2 3 4 5 1
```

Here is a demonstrative program where there is used the standard algorithm `std::rotate`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    for ( const auto &item : v )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    std::rotate( std::begin( v ), std::next( std::begin( v ) ), std::end( v ) );
    
    for ( const auto &item : v )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above

```
1 2 3 4 5 
2 3 4 5 1
```

Comment: The world needs more std::rotate.